# Protect class from UIAppearance

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview, uiappearance

I have a `UIPickerView` in a view inside a subclass of `UINavigationController`.  I have a `UIAppearance` proxy that I want to apply to many views contained in the `UINavigationController` subclass, but I don't want the `UIAppearance` to operate on the `UIPickerView`.

Is there any way to have the `UIAppearance` proxy apply to all views inside the `UINavigationController` subclass and then protect views inside specific objects from its effect?

Without UIAppearance, the screen looks like this:

[image: Without UIAppearance]

With this code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *nvcMain ;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window ;
@synthesize nvcMain ;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_ph" bundle:nil] ;
    nvcMain = [sb instantiateInitialViewController] ;
    window.rootViewController = nvcMain ;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    id apprNVCView = [UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] ;
    [apprNVCView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor] ];

    return YES;
}
```

the screen looks like this:

[image: With UIAppearance]

I don't want the subviews of the UIPickerview to be clobbered by the cyan, although I may want to apply cyan to many other views contained in the UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but here is what is happening with your code.

You are setting all the views background color to cyan inside the navigation controller.  The UIPickerView is a view so, it's color is changed.

Edit:

I think the appearance protocol is probably just overkill for what you actually want.  You want to change the color of a view behind the picker view, then just go ahead and set its background color.

```
[[self YOUR_VIEW] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

The appearance protocol works well if you want to change all of a certain view to a particular color.  For example, you want all your navigation bars to be a red color, you could set this in one spot, and it would change all navigation bars in the application.

For this to work, you would have to subclass all views you want to be that blue color, and set them with the appearance protocol method appearanceWhenContainedIn.

Comment: But, the UIPickerView is also contained in the UINavigationController, so it is getting the UIAppearance, as well as the other views.

Comment: Attach a screenshot, i'm a little confused to was you mean, you cannot customize the picker view via the appearance proxy

Comment: @gary_z check the edit, but what are you trying to change to the blue color?

Comment: Only the view that contains the UIPickerView.  But in actual practice, there may be labels for buttons, nav bar labels, etc that I would also want to change to cyan.

Comment: What I want to accomplish is to have any view that I push onto the UINavigationController to get the cyan color, while not trashing the background of all of their subviews.  I think what I'll do is make a UIView subclass for the large views, and apply the appearance to them.